# Jump Point Search fails on succession

Tags: c#, a-star

If the node cost heuristics are saved between iterations the algorithm will break after the first iteration. If the starting point and target are changed it won't find a new path. Only by clearing the costs will it find a new path. Is this normal?

Code added. Priority queue hasn't been implemented yet. It works on a grid translated from a XYZ-space in Unity 3D.

```
 if (newMovementCostToNeighbor < jumpPoint.gCost || jumpPoint.fCost <= 0)
        {
            jumpPoint.gCost = newMovementCostToNeighbor;
            jumpPoint.hCost = getDistance(jumpPoint, targetNode);
            jumpPoint.parent = currentNode;
            successors.Add(jumpPoint);
        }
```

Identified the problem in IDSuccessors, checks to see if the path cost is < the saved gcost or if jumpPoint has never been visited (if its fCost <=0). Since the check is essentially dependent on the path cost to a jumpPoint being less than the saved gCost the pathfinding breaks after being run once.

```
if (newMovementCostToNeighbor < jumpPoint.gCost || (!openSet.Contains(jumpPoint) && !closedSet.Contains(jumpPoint)) || jumpPoint.fCost <= 0)
            {
                jumpPoint.gCost = newMovementCostToNeighbor;
                jumpPoint.hCost = getDistance(jumpPoint, targetNode);
                jumpPoint.parent = currentNode;
                successors.Add(jumpPoint);
            }
```

Solution found. Supplement the check. The idea is to check if jumpPoint has never before been seen during the run, so one way is to check if it's absent from both the openSet or closedSet.

```
    void FindPath(Vector3 startPos, Vector3 targetPos)
{

    Node startNode = grid.NodeFromWorldPoint(startPos);
    Node targetNode = grid.NodeFromWorldPoint(targetPos);

    List<Node> openSet = new List<Node>();
    HashSet<Node> closedSet = new HashSet<Node>();
    openSet.Add(startNode);

    while(openSet.Count > 0)
    {
        Node currentNode = openSet[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < openSet.Count; i++)
        {
            if(openSet[i].fCost < currentNode.fCost || (openSet[i].fCost == currentNode.fCost && openSet[i].hCost < currentNode.hCost))
            {
                currentNode = openSet[i];
            }
        }

        openSet.Remove(currentNode);
        closedSet.Add(currentNode);

        if(currentNode == targetNode)
        {
            RetracePath(startNode, targetNode);
            return;
        }

        List<Node> successors = IDSuccessors(currentNode, startNode, targetNode);

        foreach(Node n in successors)
        {
            if(n != null)
            {

                openSet.Add(n);
            }
        }
    }

}

public List<Node> IDSuccessors(Node currentNode, Node startNode, Node targetNode)
{
    List<Node> successors = new List<Node>();
    List<Node> neighbors = grid.getNeighbors(currentNode);

    foreach (Node neighbor in neighbors)
    {
            int dx = Mathf.Clamp(neighbor.gridX - currentNode.gridX, -1, 1);
            int dy = Mathf.Clamp(neighbor.gridY - currentNode.gridY, -1, 1);

            Node jumpPoint = Jump(currentNode.gridX, currentNode.gridY, dx, dy, startNode, targetNode);

        if (jumpPoint != null)
        {

            int newMovementCostToNeighbor = currentNode.gCost + getDistance(currentNode, jumpPoint);
            if (newMovementCostToNeighbor < jumpPoint.gCost || jumpPoint.fCost <= 0)
            {
                jumpPoint.gCost = newMovementCostToNeighbor;
                jumpPoint.hCost = getDistance(jumpPoint, targetNode);
                jumpPoint.parent = currentNode;
                successors.Add(jumpPoint);
            }
        }


    }

    return successors;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a little more information about your implementation? Perhaps some code to look at?

Comment: I added the main method and the method for IDing successors, in which costs are evaluated.